# msp430f5438a reading multiple sensor tmp117

Tags: sensors, i2c, msp430

My code worked fine if I only connect msp430 to one sensor. However, when I connect msp430 to 4 sensors. I try to read to only one sensor but it just stop at stop condition.

I expected to read sensor values by passing the corresponding sensor address. But I'm sure what is wrong. I would appreciated any help or suggestion.

```c
#include <msp430.h>
#include "tmp117_i2C.h"

volatile uint8_t rx_val = 0;
char uartBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned int len;
int i;

// GPIO
void initGPIO()
{
    // LED
    P1OUT &= ~0x01;       // P1.0 = 0
    P1DIR |= 0x01;        // P1.0 output

    // I2C Pins
    P3SEL |= BIT1 + BIT2; // P3.0,1 option select
    // I2C Pins
    P9SEL |= BIT1 + BIT2; // P9.0,1 option select

    // UART pins
    P3SEL |= BIT4+ BIT5;  // P3.3,4 = USCI_A0 TXD/RXD
}

// UART Initialization
void initUART(void)
{
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;  // **Put state machine in reset**
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2; // SMCLK
    UCA0BR0 = 9;          // 1MHz 115200 (see User's Guide)
    UCA0BR1 = 0;          // 1MHz 115200
    UCA0MCTL |= UCBRS0;   // Modulation UCBRSx = 1
    UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST; // **Initialize USCI state machine**
    UCA0IE |= UCRXIE;     // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
}

// I2C Initialization
void initI2C(void)
{
    UCB2CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                  // Enable SW reset
    UCB2CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC; // I2C Master, synchronous mode
    UCB2CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;        // Use SMCLK
    UCB2BR0 = 12;                         // fSCL = SMCLK/12 = ~100kHz
    UCB2BR1 = 0;
    UCB2CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                 // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE |= UCTXIE + UCRXIE;            // Enable both RX and TX interrupts
                                          // UCB0IE is the interrupt register
    UCB0IE |= UCSTTIE;                    // Enable STT interrupt
}

void initI2C_Port3(void) {
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                  // Enable SW reset
    UCB0CTL0 = UCMST + UCMODE_3 + UCSYNC; // I2C Master, synchronous mode
    UCB0CTL1 = UCSSEL_2 + UCSWRST;        // Use SMCLK
    UCB0BR0 = 12;                         // Set baud rate
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;                 // Clear SW reset, resume operation
    UCB0IE |= UCRXIE + UCTXIE;            // Enable RX and TX interrupt
}

// Function to send a string
void sendString(char *str) {
    while (*str != 0) {
        while (!(UCA0IFG & UCTXIFG)); // Wait until the buffer is ready
        UCA0TXBUF = *str++;           // Send the current character
    }
}

/**
 * main.c
 */
int main(void) {
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // Stop watchdog timer
    char text[] = "MSP430 \r\n";
    // Initialize
    initGPIO();
    initUART(); //for debug purpose
    initI2C();
    initI2C_Port3();

    uint8_t sensorAddrs[] = {TMP117_ADDR_1, TMP117_ADDR_2, TMP117_ADDR_3, TMP117_ADDR_4};
    uint8_t* receiveBuffers[] = {ReceiveBuffer1, ReceiveBuffer2, ReceiveBuffer3, ReceiveBuffer4};

    __bis_SR_register(GIE); // Enable global interrupts

    // Main loop
    while (1) 
    {
        sendString(text);
        P1OUT ^= BIT0;  // Toggle P1.0 using exclusive-OR

        __delay_cycles(2000000);  // Delay between messages
        // for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //     I2C_Master_ReadReg(sensorAddrs[i], TMP117_TEMP_REG, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
        //     CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, receiveBuffers[i], TYPE_1_LENGTH);
        // }
        I2C_Master_ReadReg(TMP117_ADDR_1, TMP117_TEMP_REG, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
        CopyArray(ReceiveBuffer, SlaveType1, TYPE_1_LENGTH);
        double sensorValue = processSensorData(ReceiveBuffer[0], ReceiveBuffer[1]);

        sprintf(uartBuffer, "Received: %x %x \r\n", ReceiveBuffer[0], ReceiveBuffer[1]);
        sendString(uartBuffer);

        // floatToString(uartBuffer, sensorValue, 6);
        sprintf(uartBuffer, "Sensor Value: %f \r\n", sensorValue);
    }
}

//******************************************************************************
// I2C Interrupt ***************************************************************
//******************************************************************************

#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector=USCI_B2_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_B2_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(USCI_B2_VECTOR))) USCI_B2_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{
  // Must read from UCB2RXBUF
  // uint8_t rx_val = 0;
  switch(__even_in_range(UCB2IV,0xC)) {
    case USCI_NONE:break;            // Vector 0 - no interrupt
    
    case USCI_I2C_UCALIFG:break;     // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCALIFG
    
    case USCI_I2C_UCNACKIFG:break;   // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCNACKIFG
    
    case USCI_I2C_UCSTTIFG:          // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCSTTIFG
      // UCB0STAT &= ~UCSTTIFG;
        break;

    case USCI_I2C_UCSTPIFG:break;    // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCSTPIFG
    
    case USCI_I2C_UCRXIFG:
        rx_val = UCB2RXBUF;
        if (RXByteCtr) {
          ReceiveBuffer[ReceiveIndex++] = rx_val;
          RXByteCtr--;
        }

        if (RXByteCtr == 1) {
          UCB2CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
        } else if (RXByteCtr == 0) {
          UCB2IE &= ~UCRXIE;
          MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
          __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF); // Exit LPM0
        }
        break;                      // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCRXIFG
    
    case USCI_I2C_UCTXIFG:
        switch (MasterMode) {
          case TX_REG_ADDRESS_MODE:
              UCB2TXBUF = TransmitRegAddr;
              if (RXByteCtr)
                  MasterMode = SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE; // Need to start receiving now
              else
                  MasterMode = TX_DATA_MODE;      // Continue to transmission with the data in Transmit Buffer
              break;

          case SWITCH_TO_RX_MODE:
              UCB2IE |= UCRXIE;          // Enable RX interrupt
              UCB2IE &= ~UCTXIE;         // Disable TX interrupt
              UCB2CTL1 &= ~UCTR;         // Switch to receiver
              MasterMode = RX_DATA_MODE; // State state is to receive data
              UCB2CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;       // Send repeated start
              if (RXByteCtr == 1) {
                  //Must send stop since this is the N-1 byte
                  while((UCB2CTL1 & UCTXSTT));
                  UCB2CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;   // Send stop condition
              }
              break;

          case TX_DATA_MODE:
              if (TXByteCtr) {
                  UCB2TXBUF = TransmitBuffer[TransmitIndex++];
                  TXByteCtr--;
              } else {
                  // Done with transmission
                  UCB2CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;  // Send stop condition
                  MasterMode = IDLE_MODE;
                  UCB2IE &= ~UCTXIE;    // disable TX interrupt
                  __bic_SR_register_on_exit(CPUOFF); // Exit LPM0
              }
              break;

          default:
              __no_operation();
              break;
        }
        break;                      // Interrupt Vector: I2C Mode: UCTXIFG
    default: break;
  }
}
```